# WebView flickering using it in TabHost

Tags: android, webview, tabs, android-tabhost

My app uses TabHost where each tabs content is a WebView. While testing on my device I've noticed that the WebViews sometimes flickers when I change tabs. I've tried adding `android:layerType="software"` to the WebViews, but no result.

It blinks only the first time I tap on a tab.